# AWS ES See my Automated Snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, snapshot

I would like to list the automated snapshot from my Elastisearch ressources but I can't find where they are.

I tried this:

```
curl -XGET 'curl -XGET 'elasticsearch-domain-endpoint/_snapshot?pretty' 
it return {"Message":"User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpGet...}
```

I see that I may need a signed request but it looks time-consumming to understand and to use it so i prefer to find an easy and fast solution.

I try to find the cs-automated repository on S3 but I can't find it...

I assume that my automatic snapshots are enabled because of this in my ES ressources details :
Start hour for the daily automated snapshot00:00 UTC (default)

If someone has any idea to share I take it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: using [awscurl](https://github.com/okigan/awscurl) should be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS stores this in a S3 bucket and no additional cost which is not visible for you.

According to the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains-snapshots.html#es-managedomains-snapshot-restore) the CURL request you provided is the correct one, but it indeed required authentication. You could also modify your access policy to allow everyone access, but I would not advise that.

You could try to take a look at [awscurl](https://github.com/okigan/awscurl)